# AngularJS: How to guarantee $broadcast/$emit fires only after the handlers are setup

Tags: angularjs

[Here is the jsfiddle for a maybe contrived example](http://jsfiddle.net/eze123/ADukg/2378/)

```
$scope.dataLoaded = function (){
  var response = "payload";
  $scope.$broadcast("dataLoaded", response);
  console.log("broadcasted");
}


// will not work if setup after message broadcasted
$scope.$on("dataLoaded", $scope.setData);
```

The basic questions is this: 
In an asynchronous application, where the data load order cannot be guaranteed. can we rely on $broadcast/$emit to manage data loading.

It so, how do we guarantee the handlers will receive broadcasted messages, and is there any best practices around event firing and handlering so it won't get too messy.

If not, what are alternatives(e.g. maybe defer/promise)?

Thanks

Comment: In your example "dataLoaded" event is sent to 2 seconds earlier than "users" would be created. So, sure, they will not able to process it just because it gone already. Event or promise is just phone call which is instantaneous. It notify its listeners about something and it is gone.

Comment: right, my question is that it is very easy to write code with bugs like this. How do we avoid them?

Comment: All depends from what you need. AngularJS is not one-stop solution for all cases. So, in my opinion, your question more about how to design application (independent from language, framework and so on) than how to do it in AngularJS.

Comment: "how to design application" - the first thing that comes to mind is MVC with all its variations. Next thing which comes to mind - State Machine. As I wrote all depends from what you need to implement in current case. There are no one-stop solutions, there are trends and principles that should be followed. Sure, everything what I wrote is just my opinion.